# Broadcast live video from web-cam via plug-in

Tags: video, plugins, webcam, live, broadcasting

Could you please suggest me what kind of software should I use to broadcast live video from webcam? Web-cam is connected via USB to my server. I want to broadcast video from my webcam on my web-page (HTML, ASP.NET - doesn't matter). I don't want to develop video broadcasting from the beginning - it takes a lot of time to implement good system. I'm looking for ready-to-use plug-in/widget for my site. 
I found ustream.tv, but live video **start playing with delay about 2 seconds**... You know, it's not real-time. 
I need something like Skype/icq/ooVoo... plug-in/widget for my web-site. Are these plug-ins exists in internet?
P.S. I know that VideoLAN has ActiveX control. Does VLC provide me with real-time video broadcasting from webcam without any delays like Skype? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be as probable approaches (I do not know about delays in the cases):

- Use Windows Media Encoder as broadcaster. In this case you do not need a server software at all. But number of clients is restricted to 50.
- Use Windows Media server (If you use a Windows server platform).

Comment: I've tested and compared Windows Media Encoder and VideoLAN. Each of these variants is real-time, but each of them has delays about 3-4 seconds... Delays doesn't depend on framerates and quality of video. I tested videostream 800Kb/s (320x240), and 16KB/s (160x190 15 fps) - there are no differences in delays.

Comment: My server internet connection has 2Megabit in and 1Megabit out speed, client has about 4Megabit incoming speed. How can I avoid these delays??

Comment: Delays may have various nature: delays of codecs and "network" delays (because of buffering on client or server side etc.). At least you should first guarantee, that you use low-delay video (and audio, if used) codecs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems that delays happens due to something like buffering...